# restricting access to read and write from queue

Tags: binding, client, authorization, ibm-mq

I have a scenarios where one server hosts some queues under a queue manager and another server host an application which need access to those queues. The application connects using client-binding (using server-connection channel). I want to restrict the application to be able to just read from one queue and write to another queue (probably by setting an MCAUSER on the SVRCONN channel). 
Whats the minimum sufficient authorisation a user will require in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading from the queue you will need to enable `get` permission on the queue from which you want allow read only. For example

```
setmqaut -m QM -t queue -n READ.LOCAL.QUEUE -g groupa +inq +get -put
```

To allow put only:

```
setmqaut -m QM -t queue -n WRITE.LOCAL.QUEUE -g groupa +inq -get +put
```

This [link](https://t-rob.net/2008/07/08/websphere-mq-security-heats-up/) from T-Rob's blog has more details: